# Изобразить круг образованный пересечением сферы с плоскостью

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно вписать уравнения в код. Проблема в том, что программа выводит неправильную фигуру. А еще нужно сделать так, чтобы фигуры обоих уравнений были выведены вместе на одном изображении.

Выражены уравнения:

```
z = -2*x + 2*y + 7

z = sqrt((-x**2 + 4*x - y**2 + 221)) + 5
z = 5 - sqrt((-x**2 + 4*x - y**2 + 221))
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.005)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.005)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = -2*x + 2*y + 7

#оси x, y, z
ax.plot([0,0], [0,14], [0,0], '>-r')
ax.plot([0,0], [-14,0], [0,0], '-r')
ax.plot([0,14], [0,0], [0,0], '>-r')
ax.plot([-14,0], [0,0], [0,0], '-r')
ax.plot([0,0], [0,0], [0,1.8], '^-r')
ax.plot([0,0], [0,0], [-1.3,0], '-r')


surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z / 2, linewidth=0, antialiased=True, color='blue')

ax.set_title('Task 2')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый ваш вопрос *"Проблема в том, что программа выводит неправильную фигуру".*
Что значит "неправильную"? Выводится та фигура, которую вы задали. Какой-то клаптик поверхности сферы.

Напомню, что на этом сайте существует правило: Один топик  -  один вопрос. Но поскольку ответ на второй вопрос  -  *"нужно сделать так, чтобы фигуры обоих уравнений были выведены вместе на одном изображении"*.  тривиален, приведу и ответ на него.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.005)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.005)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = -2*x + 2*y + 7
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z / 2, color='red')
z = (np.sqrt((-x**2 + 4*x - y**2 + 221)) + 5)
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z / 2,  color='blue')
z = (-np.sqrt((-x**2 + 4*x - y**2 + 221))+5)
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z / 2,  color='green')
```

Синим и зеленым цветом - это те самые фрагменты сферы (можно по рисунку понять):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме того,хочу заметить, что matplotlib  -  это не пакет решения системы уравнений, т.е. он не способен сам построить отдельную фигуру - кривую пересечения. Он просто рисует вам те фигуры, которые вы ему явно задали нарисовать. И не более.